# neo4j reserved word exception

Tags: neo4j, reserved-words

I get this:

```
-sh (?)$ START  n=node:words(word='test11'), m=node:defintions(defintion='definition 11'), CREATE UNIQUE n-[:HS {certainty: 1}]->m;
==> SyntaxException: reserved keyword
```

The code fails in the Java app so I tested in the Console and it stopped on UNIQUE.

I am trying to create a relationship between word and definition (a more general NLP app and this the basic start).

I saw in the docs multiple ways of making the relationships, eg using MATCH and the whole thing gets confusing to me with so many different ways.

Has anyone got any idea why the above query failed?

Comment: What is the meaning of UNIQUE keyword here??

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE defines it. The relationship should be created uniquely, that is what I assumed it did.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
START  n=node:words(word='test11'), m=node:defintions(defintion='definition 11') CREATE UNIQUE n-[r:HS {certainty: 1}]->m RETURN r;
```

Comment: Not working still. The code did work, so maybe something changed in Neo4j.

Comment: I don't understand.. you said "Not working", and after that "The code did work"... how that??

Comment: I copied some old code I had and the code did work. Now it will not work. I assume therefore that Neo4j has changed.

Comment: I have some debugging statements: failed=org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestResultException: reserved keyword
"START  n=node:words(word='test1121'), m=node:definitions(definition='definition 1121'), CREATE UNIQUE n-[:HAS {certainty: 1}]->m"
                                                                                                ^ at
SyntaxException
   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.parser.v1_8.CypherParserImpl.parse(CypherParserImpl.scala:45)
   org.neo4j.cypher.CypherParser.parse(CypherParser.scala:42)
   or

Comment: Brilliant. That worked. I'll buy you lunch in the UK if you come here.

Comment: Well, I was banging my head against the wall on that one. Check out the site when it is running - wordsuit.com

Comment: The site is linked to YouTube.. When can we access the full site ??